# Angular 2/4 can't read object in initForm()

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular2-http, angular2-observables

I'm creating an edit form in angular and I'm confused about the lifecycle of the object that is returned from my backend server. When I make a call to my service in `ngOnInit()`, I get workable data.  When I assign that to an instance variable, It is undefined in `initForm()` even though I'm calling `initForm()` after assigning that data.

If you look at the console.log statements you will see that the object works inside the `ngOnInit()` function but not in `initForm()`. What am I missing here?  How do I make this.data accessible by the entire component?

payee-edit.component.ts:

```
export class PayeeEditComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  public payee: Payee;
  id: number;
  payeeEditForm: FormGroup;
  data: Payee;
  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute, private payeeService: PayeeService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params
      .subscribe(
        (params: Params) => {
          this.id = +params['id'];
          this.subscription = this.payeeService.getPayee(this.id).subscribe(
            data => {
              this.data = data;
              console.log(this.data.company); //THIS WORKS
            }
          );
        }
      );
    this.initForm();

  }
  private initForm() {
    console.log(this.data.company); //THIS RETURNS UNDEFINED
    let payeeCompany = 'this.data.company';
    let payeeFirstName =  'this.data.first_name;'
    let payeeLastName = 'this.data.last_name;'
    let payeeNotes = 'this.data.notes;'

    this.payeeEditForm = new FormGroup({
      'company': new FormControl(payeeCompany),
      'first_name': new FormControl(payeeFirstName),
      'last_name': new FormControl(payeeLastName),
      'notes': new FormControl(payeeNotes)
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

payee.service.ts:

```
  getPayee(id: number) {
    return this.http.get(`http://localhost:3000/payees/${id}`)
    .map(data => data.json());
  }
```

Edit:
If I put the call to initForm() inside the subscription, I get an error on page load complaining that initForm() needs to be called. It doesn't work until I fire the event that triggers the getPayee() call. I understand now why I'm getting the behavior now, so thank you for the link. I just need a little help with my specific use case

Comment: If I put the call to `initForm()` inside the subscription, I get an error on page load complaining that `initForm()` needs to be called. It doesn't work until I fire the event that triggers the `getPayee()` call.  I understand now why I'm getting the behavior now, so thank you for the link.  I just need a little help with my specific use case.

Comment: What is the exact error message? And I just noticed you are using string values... `let payeeCompany='this.data.company'` will be the string literal. You should use: `let payeeCompany=this.data.company` But you could also just assign it when you build the form `'company': newFormControl(this.data.company)`. But tell me the exact error message and let's see if I can help out :)

Comment: @AJT_82.  Lol yeah those string values were to silence the undefined error so I could troubleshoot.  I'm going to try your answer when you get home.  It looks like it will work.

Comment: sure thing! Let me know how it goes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First issue is that the call is asynchronous, so `initForm` is called before data has been retrieved. More info here: [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular2) So you need to call the method inside the callback.

Tested the code, and so it seems, that when you add the `initForm` inside the callback it still doesn't work, **even though** setting the form with `*ngIf="data"`. Still the form gets rendered before the form has been completely built, which throws error.

So I see two possibilities here. Set a boolean value, e.g `showForm` and do not render the form unless `showForm` is true. You set the flag `showForm` as true, after data has been retrieved **and** after the form has been built.

Other option would be to use `setValue` (or `patchValue`) where you enter the data to the fields after retrieving the data. Here's an example for you:

build the form in your `OnInit` with empty values:

```ts
this.payeeEditForm = new FormGroup({
  'company': new FormControl()
  'first_name': new FormControl()
  'last_name': new FormControl()
  'notes': new FormControl()
})
```

And when retrieved data call `patchForm` in the callback:

```ts
this.subscription = this.payeeService.getPayee(this.id)
   .subscribe(data => {
      this.data = data;
      this.patchForm(); // set the values to the form
   });
```

and your `patchForm`-method:

```ts
patchForm() {
  this.payeeEditForm.setValue({
    company: this.data.company,
    first_name: this.data.first_name,
    last_name: this.data.last_name,
    notes: this.data.notes
  });
}
```

This seems to work fine! :) And setting the boolean flag worked too, if you prefer that!

Here's a

### [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/aR9pXB4egmWnYu336AII?p=preview)

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Comment: Great! Glad to hear :)

Answer (score 0):

The callback that you give to the subscribe method is executed later than the initForm method. Because the http call takes X amount of time.

What you could do is to bind all of the properties to the ([ngModel]) in the inputs.

Comment: I'm using reactive forms (data driven). will ng model work?

Comment: call  initForm() after this.data = data;

Comment: @aimprogman.  If I call it there I get an error on page load about `initForm()` not being called.  It does work after I fire the click event calling `getPayee()`, but since I'm not calling `initForm()` on page load, the form doesn't load presenting the error.