# Angular 2 ngModel cant reach Array property

Tags: angular, typescript

Hello fellow programmer,

after i make an API call i convert the JSON to an array.

This array will display in an Component inside an HTML table, after you pressed the "edit" button the Component will change his content from an HTML table to an HTML form, where you can edit the Data, which Data you can send back to the API server.

component.html

```
        <div *ngFor="let rule of generateArray(gutschein['ruleset_list']['rulesets']); let i = index" >
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Rule: </label> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rule{{i}}" 
                requierd
                [(ngModel)]="rule['condition']['expression']" name="rule"  #rule="ngModel">
                <div [hidden]="rule.valid || rule.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
                    Rule is not valid
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Discount: </label> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="discount{{i}}" 
                requierd
                [(ngModel)]="rule['results']['results'][i+1]['calculation']" name="discount"  #discount="ngModel">
                <div [hidden]="discount.valid || discount.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
                    Discount is not valid
                </div>
            </div>
```

component.ts

```
generateArray(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).map((key) => { return obj[key] });
}
```

it seems like the `ngModel` cant reache my `this.rule['condition']['expression']` Data.

If i changed it to `this.rule['condition']` it works perfectly.

Any Idea how I can fixed this problem? I would be thankfull for an explanation not only the fixed code.

JSON

```
    {
        "id": "1",
        "code": "A1234",
        "valid": null,
        "ruleset_list": {
            "rulesets": {
                "1": {
                    "id": "1",
                    "voucher_id": "1",
                    "condition": {
                        "expression": "shop.totalamount > `15` && current_datetime < `1490021400`"
                    },
                    "results": {
                        "results": {
                            "1": {
                                "id": "1",
                                "value_path": "shop.totalamount",
                                "calculation": "#VALUE * 0.9",
                                "new_value": null
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "2": {
                    "id": "2",
                    "voucher_id": "1",
                    "condition": {
                        "expression": "shop.totalamount > `20` && current_datetime < `1490021400`"
                    },
                    "results": {
                        "results": {
                            "2": {
                                "id": "2",
                                "value_path": "shop.totalamount",
                                "calculation": "#VALUE * 0.8",
                                "new_value": null
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `this` is not supposed to be defined in the template... `this.someVar` won't work `someVar` will work like a charm.

Comment: @n00dl3 i already tried that too, didnt work either.

Comment: after removing `this` from template if not working as expected then there should be something else with logic but currently the syntax is wrong remove `this` from everywhere and update the answer

Comment: and provide the structure of the data you are trying to access.

Comment: @BabarBilal i will update it in a second, would you mind to tell me why using `.this` is wrong in this context?

Comment: @n00dl3 i uploaded my JSON

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your root cause is `#rule="ngModel"` and `#discount="ngModel"`. You are already using two-way binding, so do not declare a [**template reference**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ref-vars) as ngModel. The template reference value and the two way binding do not go together. As per said [**here**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html#!#template-input-variable):

> Template input and reference variable names have their own namespaces. The `hero` in `let hero` is never the same variable as the `hero` declared as `#hero`.

So I guess you could basically say that there two variables "*fight each other*" and clash.

Furthermore, you can also use dot notation in your ngModels, so the following are equal:

```
rule['condition']['expression']
```

and

```
rule.condition.expression
```

I won't go into that any closer, since here are great answers: **[Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)**. But you can of course use bracket notation if you like :)

**EDIT:**

Missed the fact, that each name attribute needs to be unique so that the form fields are evaluated as different form fields, and not one and the same. So you can use the index to do that:

`name="rule{{i}}"` and `name="discount{{i}}"`

Finally, a plunker to play with:

### [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/pIGS0LKjg2Y14j650B5e?p=preview)

PS. I would perhaps actually suggest you use reactive forms here now, that would be easier to handle, since by removing the template reference you will have trouble with the validation. With reactive forms, you can skip the ngModels altogether and set the default values to the form control and also handle the validation. Here more info about [**dynamic forms**](https://scotch.io/tutorials/using-angular-2s-model-driven-forms-with-formgroup-and-formcontrol) and [nested dynamic forms](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-build-nested-model-driven-forms-in-angular-2), as that is what you would need.

Here's a recent [**question and answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43266967/angular-2-4-cant-read-object-in-initform) with values coming from http-request, meaning just like yours you need to set empty form controls first and when you want to edit form use `setvalue` or `patchvalue` to set the pre values to your form. Depending on your use case, maybe you won't need to use patchValue at all. BUT in case you need.

Comment: On your plunker you print out the the same value twice, not  two different values. But your ngFor is working perfectly, i tested it with the outprint from the var `i`. Can you fixed it and tell me what went wrong? 

so far, ty for the respone. I will test it tomorrow at work!

Comment: Yeah, I missed the fact that name attribute has to be unique ;) Thanks for pointing that out. That is fixed now, but perhaps consider using reactive forms here instead. I'd think that would be the best solution for you actually. Check the updated answer, there are some useful links that hopefully can help you! :)